# Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'ColorHair' at row 1

Tags: php, mysql

Hey so am getting this error

Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'ColorHair' at row 1

Can anybody please help me or give me a fix for this D:

> $sql2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` (`Username`, `Password`, `Access`, `ActivationFlag`, `Age`, `Gender`, `Email`, `Level`, `Gold`, `Coins`, `Exp`, `ColorHair`, `ColorSkin`, `ColorEye`, `ColorBase`, `ColorTrim`, `ColorAccessory`, `DateCreated`, `LastLogin`, `UpgradeExpire`, `UpgradeDays`, `BankSlots`, `HouseSlots`, `BagSlots`, `HairID`, `HairFile`, `HairName`, `Permamute`, `Quests`, `Quests2`, `Settings`, `Achievement`, `LastArea`, `Country`, `Founder`, `GuildID`, `AchievementID`, `RankID`, `HouseInfo`, `Kills`, `Deaths`, `GuildRank`, `CurrentServer`, `DailyQuest0`, `DailyQuest1`, `DailyQuest2`, `MonthlyQuest0`, `Upgraded`, `XpBoost`, `CpBoost`, `GoldBoost`) VALUES ('$username', '$pass1', '1', '5', '15', '$gender', '$email', '1', '0', '0', '0', '$haircolor', '$skincolor', '$eyecolor', '0', '0', '0', '$time', '$time', '$time', '-1', '0', '10', '40', '$hairid', '$hairfile', '$hairname', '0', '00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000', '00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000', '0', '0', '', 'US', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'Offline', '', '', '', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0');")  or die("status=Error&strReason=" . mysql_error());

Comment: `'$haircolor'` is an empty string, meaning that $haircolor is something that evaluates to an empty string when used in a string context.

Answer (score 1):

Your "ColorHair" column is of type integer, and you pass it the value of an empty string : ''

If your db field accept null for this field you may consider adding this line of PHP before doing your request :

```
$haircolor = intval($haircolor);
```